# How can I improve the performance of template matching with opencv?

Tags: python, rectangles, screen-capture, template-matching, drawrectangle

I'm quite new at python.

In short, I want the code to capture the part of the screen where the application window is located and find the template I need in this window. But since I know that this template is only in a certain part of the window, to improve performance, I want the code to look for template only in this part, but display the entire window. I almost completed my task, but I ran into the fact that the code draws a square in the wrong position where exactly the template is due to the fact that the window and its part have different coordinates.

Here is all the code.

```
import time

import cv2
import mss
import numpy as np
from templates import death_img, defeat_img, exit_img, start_img, zero_img, death_h, death_w, defeat_h, defeat_w, exit_h, exit_w, start_w, start_h, zero_w, zero_h


with mss.mss() as sct:
    # Part of the screen to capture
    tmcheck = {"top": 100, "left": 37, "width": 409, "height": 76}
    mon = {"top": 35, "left": 2, "width": 480, "height": 270}

    while "Screen capturing":
        last_time = time.time()

        # Get raw pixels from the screen, save it to a Numpy array
        img = np.array(sct.grab(mon))
        tm = np.array(sct.grab(tmcheck))
        threshold = .60
        result = cv2.matchTemplate(tm, zero_img, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
        yloc, xloc = np.where(result >= threshold)

        rectangles = []
        for (x, y) in zip(xloc, yloc):
            rectangles.append([int(x), int(y), int(zero_w), int(zero_h)])
            rectangles.append([int(x), int(y), int(zero_w), int(zero_h)])

        rectangles, weights = cv2.groupRectangles(rectangles, 1, 0.2)

        for (x, y, zero_w, zero_h) in rectangles:
          img = cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + zero_w, y + zero_h), (0,255,255), 2)

        print(rectangles)


        # Display the picture
        cv2.imshow("AI Eyes", img)

        print("fps: {}".format(1 / (time.time() - last_time)))

        # Press "q" to quit
        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
```

And [here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Khis4.png) the result I am getting

And yes, maybe I can somehow improve the import of templates and their parameters? Because I'm sure that my method is rather strange and inefficient.

```
from templates import death_img, defeat_img, exit_img, start_img, zero_img, death_h, death_w, defeat_h, defeat_w, exit_h, exit_w, start_w, start_h, zero_w, zero_h
```